# socket io unique channel - emit without specifying the room

Tags: socket.io

On my project each user is joining his unique channel (I know that the user is also in a socked id channel).

Client

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8000/');
var room = "unique_id";

socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.emit('room', room);
});

socket.on("unique_id", function() {
    console.log("test");
})
```

On the server side I am checking the rooms a user is connected to:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var room;

    socket.on('room', function(unique_id) {
        socket.join(unique_id);
        room = unique_id;
        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms); //show the unique_id room
        io.to(room).emit('hello', 'msg');
    });

    socket.on(room, function(data) {
        console.log(room);
    })

});
```

Output on connect

```
{ 'DQOt2DX2IsHh-m9nAAAC': { sockets: { 'DQOt2DX2IsHh-m9nAAAC': true }, length: 1 },
'unique_id': { sockets: { 'DQOt2DX2IsHh-m9nAAAC': true }, length: 1 } }
```

Now I am using elephant.io to emit to the client as follows

```
$client = new Client(new Version1X('http://localhost:8000'));
$client->initialize();
$client->emit('unique_id', ['news' => 'bar']);
$client->close();
```

I think there is something wrong on my server side but I am not able to solve it. I need to process the events for the unique_id but how?

Answer (score 0):

server side

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var room;

    socket.on('room', function(address) {
        socket.join(address);
        room = address;
        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
        io.to(room).emit('hello', 'msg');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log(data.unique_id);
        io.to(data.unique_id).emit('hello', 'msg');
    })

});
```

elephant.io

```
$client->emit('message', ['unique_id' => 'foo']);
```

This is my solution which is working for me.